# Python/Selenium Read Website Timer in Realtime

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

How can I read a website timer using selenium in real-time for example for the following website

http://www.timer-tab.com/

I need to read the time and perform some operations in fraction of a second. I have the following code to read the timer but im open to suggestions.

```
def timer_value(mydriver):
    timer_element = mydriver.find_element_by_css_selector("#time")
    #print timer_element.text
    h, m, s = timer_element.text.split(':')
    return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)
print timer_value(mydriver)-1
```

I need to emulate the click operation on a button on the page (above website is not the one I am working on) in real-time (with around 0.01) second delay might be fine. Is it possible to do at all?